# Is "inline" required for "void f(auto) {}" in a header?

Tags: c++, templates, inline, auto, c++20

Consider

```
template<typename T>
inline void f(T) {} // "inline" can be safely removed.
```

and

```
inline void f(auto) {} // Can "inline" also be safely removed?
```

As per the C++ standard, **can** `inline` **be safely removed in the latter case?**

Comment: If the "latter case" gets included and used in two or more translation units, where it's called with the same parameter type, of course not. That should be fairly obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's a template though, and at least regular templates are implicitly inline.

Comment: **Both** of these `inline`s have a [meaning](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1498r1.html) in a module context, even if they’re class members.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat template does not imply inline!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [[dcl.fct]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-18):

> An abbreviated function template is a function declaration that has one or more generic parameter type placeholders ([dcl.spec.auto]). An abbreviated function template is **equivalent to a function template** ([temp.fct]) whose template-parameter-list includes one invented type template-parameter for each generic parameter type placeholder of the function declaration, in order of appearance.

Emphasis added. That doesn't leave a lot of wiggle room for `inline` not being the default.

Comment: Templates aren’t inline by default, though (which matters in modules); they’re just mentioned *alongside* inline functions (and variables) in the ODR.